# Unable to get fingerprint in browser using Apache JMeter

Tags: apache, jmeter

I performed performance testing using Apache JMeter version 3.X.

At one of the step, I'm not able to get the browser fingerprint value. I receive NULL value and it cause my program to be terminated.

But when I'm using normal browser, it works find.

Is there any limitation on Apache JMeter where it cannot get the browser fingerprint value?

Answer (score 0):

1. First of be aware that [it's recommended to use latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-jmeter-5.2/) (or whatever is the latest stable version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page)
2. With regards to the "fingerprint" itself, according to the [main page of JMeter project](http://jmeter.apache.org/):

   > **JMeter is not a browser**, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however **JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages**. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

   so you need to investigate the logic of this "fingerprint" check, you can make JMeter to behave like a real browser up to certain extent like:

   - use [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to represent browser cookies
   - use [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to send at least User-Agent and other headers which normal browser sends
   - etc.

   however if the "fingerprint" check relies on JavaScript you will need to re-implement the same JavaScript using [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

The main rule is: the network footprint of JMeter must be exactly the same as network footprint of the real browser (apart from dynamic values which need to be correlated), if you will send proper requests using JMeter - your system under test will not see the difference.